# Attempt to run italc at boot

Tags: boot

I'm a student sys-admin for my schools CS Program and we use a piece of software called italc in order to monitor students during exams and class and so forth. However the only way I've managed to get it to work is to add the ica executable inside of each students home directory so that it run when they log in.

The professor who I report to would like to make it boot at system start up. So I researched and wrote a LSBInit script and put it in init.d. However when I attempt to run it as a service instead of just through init.d it will not start. I believe this is because XOpenDisplay is failing to run in the clean environment ran that service runs in but I'm unsure of how to remedy this. Below is my init.d script.

```
#!/bin/bash
## BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     ica
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    italc daemon
### END INIT INFO


# Using the lsb functions to perform the operations.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

# Process name ( For display )
NAME=ica

# Daemon name, where is the actual executable
DAEMON=/bin/ica

# pid file for the daemon
PIDFILE=/var/run/ica.pid
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
DISPLAY=":0"

# If the daemon is not there, then exit.
test -x $DAEMON || exit 5

case $1 in
start)
# Checked the PID file exists and check the actual status of process
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
        status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "$NAME process" $$ status="0" || status="$?"
        # If the status is SUCCESS then don't need to start again.
        if [ "$status" = "0" ]; then
            exit # Exit
        fi
    fi
    # Start the daemon.
    log_daemon_msg "Starting the process" "$NAME"
    # Start the daemon with the help of start-stop-daemon
    # Log the message appropriately
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --make-pidfile ; then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
    fi
;;
stop)
# Stop the daemon.
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
        status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "Stopping the $NAME process" && status="0" || status="$?"
        echo "$status"
        if [ "$status" = "0" ]; then
            start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
            /bin/rm -rf $PIDFILE
        fi
    else
        log_daemon_msg "$NAME process is not running"
        log_end_msg 0
    fi
;;
restart)
# Restart the daemon.
    $0 stop && sleep 2 && $0 start
;;
status)
# Check the status of the process.
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
        status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "$NAME process" && exit 0 || exit $?
    else
        log_daemon_msg "$NAME Process is not running"
        log_end_msg 0
    fi
;;
*)
# For invalid arguments, print the usage message.
echo "Usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|status)"
    exit 2
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

go to startup applications preferences and than click on add type the name off the program and use to command from the file or thing and click add and thats about it :D

Comment: Is this a startup at system boot or a startup at user login? I've done this process on our lab kubuntu machines and it simply adds the binary to the users ~/.kde/Autostart directory. This is how the system is currently set to start italc at login in but we're trying to find a solution that will start it at system boot instead. We've kinda come to the decision that it can't run at system start up because it requires a display to be started, and it appears that the display does not start until user log in.